# Running a batch file to execute a python script using base conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFhR3.png)I have scoured google and SO and cannot get my .bat file to run properly:

this is what I have:

```
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
"c:\Users\my name\Documents\04 PRG\VS Code\Python\Scripts\myscript.py" cmd /k
```

When I run this it opens up my file with VS code and then stalls. I would like it to just run my script without opening anything.

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe you're missing the call to run Python in the batch file. 

Try: call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
python "c:\Users\my name\Documents\04 PRG\VS Code\Python\Scripts\myscript.py" cmd /k

Comment: Is the virtual environment being activated correctly? e.g. when you run call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" in a terminal. Additionally, try using `python` to run the program: `python c:\Users\my name\Documents\04 PRG\VS Code\Python\Scripts\myscript.py`

Comment: Neither of these quite solve me 100% I can get base to activate but it won't run my script for some reason. I have added what prints out when I run it manually in VS code and it succeeds.

Comment: I can get python to come up when I run the batch now I just cannot get the script to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" 
python "C:\Users\me\Documents\04 PRG\VS Code\Python\Scripts\myscript.py"
```